# Quadratic equation with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

If $\gamma$ and $\overline\gamma$ solve the equation $z^2+az+b=0$ and $\gamma$ is not a real number (complex number or just an imaginary number), does it mean that necessarily $a$ and $b$ are real numbers?

same with $z^3+az^2+bz+c=0$, can $a$, $b$ and $c$ necessarily be real numbers?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $z^2+az+b=(z-\gamma)(z-\bar\gamma)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. This is an interesting question, but what are your thoughts on it? You'll get a better response from the community if you say what you've tried.

Comment: I did try what Arthur hinted, and I know that a can be 0 and b can be 1, which means they can be real, but I don't know still if they can be complex numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the quadratic case:

Say $f(x) = x^2 + ax + b$ factors as $f(x) = (x-\alpha)(x- \overline{\alpha})$.  Re-expanding, we get $f(x) = x^2 - (\alpha + \overline{\alpha})x + \alpha \overline{\alpha}$.  Because $\alpha$ and $\overline{\alpha}$ are complex conjugates, their sum has an imaginary part of $0$.  Likewise, you can check that $\alpha \overline{\alpha} = |\alpha|^2$, which is real.

You could use a similar approach to investigate the cubic.  Note also that if a cubic has complex roots but *real* coefficients, then exactly one of its roots must be real because complex roots of polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ come in conjugate pairs.

In generality, the coefficients of a monic polynomial are [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Properties) evaluated at its roots; this fact is of great importance in the [theory of equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_equations) and [Galois thoery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory).

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: Why does one of its root must be a real number? What do you mean by complex roots come in conjugate pairs?

Comment: @toothpick, for any polynomial $f$, if $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ is a root of $f$, then so too is $\overline{\alpha}$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem

Comment: Because of that, a polynomial must have an even number of non-real roots.  So cubics must have at least one real root.  You can see this graphically since cubics go way off in one direction as $x \rightarrow - \infty$ and way off in the other direction as $x \rightarrow \infty$...the intermediate value theorem demands $f(x) = 0$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @KajHansen `complex roots come in conjugate pairs` That's only true for polynomials with *real* coefficients, which may be worth emphasizing in the context of OP's question.

Comment: Thank you :) I understand it now

Comment: Oh yes, that's a good point @dxiv; I got ahead of myself.  Of course, one could create an arbitrary polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ by just taking $(x-w_1)(x-w_2)(x-w_3)$ for $w_i$ all non-real.

Comment: Does that mean that it is possible that in the cubic case a,b,c can be not real numbers if the equation has 3 non-real roots?

Comment: Indeed @toothpick

Comment: @toothpick, it takes care of the odd-degree cases just fine, but you should consider even degree cases.  For example, if we have $n$ pairs of complex conjugate roots, do we necessarily get a degree $2n$ polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$?